# nginx urldecoding slashes in url

Tags: nginx

Nginx seems to be urldecode and match urls when I sent them. Is there anyway to prevent that?

`curl https://localhost/schedule/Joe+%2F+%26+Smith`

Is getting matched by

`rewrite ^/schedule/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /a.php?first=$1&last=$2;`

Instead of

`rewrite ^/schedule/([^/]+)$ /a.php?fullname=$1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that easily.

[From location directive documentation :](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

> The matching is performed against a normalized URI, after decoding the text encoded in the “%XX” form, resolving references to relative path components “.” and “..”, and possible compression of two or more adjacent slashes into a single slash.

Now, you can use the (very) experimental [perl module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html) and encode `$r->uri`back in a custom handler.